# Density of distribution

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, probability, distribution

I want to implement function func() which completes following task:
the average weight of car is `m` kg, with a standard deviation of `s` kg. What part of all cars would you expect to have weight more than `k` kg (probability must be `<1`)?

```
import scipy.stats as sts
def func(m, s, k):   
  norm_rv = sts.norm(loc=m, scale=s)
  return round(norm_rv.cdf(k), 4)
print('Result:', func(25, 3, 27))
```

Result is `0.7475`, but it must be `0.2546`
what have I done wrong?

Comment: I'm fairly sure your result is wrong. Perhaps you meant to call func(27, 3, 25)?

Comment: What makes you think that weights are normally distributed?  If you don't know the distribution, you should be using Chebyshev's inequality, which gives non-parametric bounds.

Answer (score 1):

`norm_rv.cdf(k)` returns the probability that the random variable takes on a value *less than or equal to* `k`.

Your implementation should be

```
import scipy.stats as sts
def func(m, s, k):   
    norm_rv = sts.norm(loc=m, scale=s)
    return round(1 - norm_rv.cdf(k), 4) # This is where the change is
print('Result:', func(25, 3, 27))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, read the documentation: `cdf` is the cumulative distribution function, the integral from -infinity to the given point.  In short, it's the proportion of cars weighing *no more* than `k`.  You need to subtract the value from 1.0000.

This gets you the value 0.2525.  I'm not sure why you expect 0.2546.

Answer (score 0):

```
norm_rv.sf(k), 4
```

Survival function (also defined as 1 - cdf, but sf is sometimes more accurate). https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html